# Angular8 routing : force all children to run their constructor, ngOnInit

Tags: angular, routes

I have the following routing:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', children: [
      {path: '', pathMatch: 'prefix', redirectTo: 'timing'},
      {path: 'timing', component: TimingComponent},
      {path: 'fio', component: FioComponent},
      {path: 'rsp', component: RspComponent}, 
    ]
  }
];
```

I have a global service that opens a file and has to display data from this file to all the children. 
But at this point, only 'timing' is alive. 'fio','rsp' are undefined.

Is it possible to make 'fio','rsp' to run also ?
In the global service I tried:

```
this.router.navigate(['/timing']).then(()=>{
        this.timing.UpdateView (val.Root.Timing);
        this.router.navigate (['fio']).then (()=>{ 
          this.fio.UpdateView (val.Root.Fio);
        })
```

But this does not work.

Thank you in advance,
Zvika

Comment: Do you want all visible at a same time? means `timing` , `fio`, and `rsp` are all visible at same time to

Comment: Services don't have children. Just inject correct service to display one data downloaded in service in multiple components.

Comment: Each time only one is visible. Upon start, timing is visible. At this point, the constructor and ngOnInit of 'fio', 'rsp' were not run yet. Is there any way to inject data to 'fio', 'rsp' at this point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you inject data downloaded by `some.service.ts` file in multiple components.

**app.module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [MyService], // provide service
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Service is just an example that im creating variable inside to hold data there.

**my.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    data: Observable<any>

    getData() {
        this.data = this.http.get() // http call to get data or other way to get data.
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private myServ: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myServ.getData() // Calling function to load data
  }
}
```

**Example child components:**

```js
export class FioComponent {

  data$: Observable<any>

  constructor(private myServ: MyService) {} // when injecting service there have to be private, public or protected statement.

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data$ = this.myServ.data
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It seems that a child can see the data only after it's ngOnInit was run. Is it possible that 'MyService' will somehow cause the ngOnInit of a child to run ?

Comment: @ZviVered Components in a browser are in real time added and removed to a view and `ngOnInit()` function is running each time when component is added to view.

Comment: @ZviVered Only `AppComponent` shows only once and run only once `ngOnInit()` function. But this component is a root component.

Comment: @ZviVered type arrow up in answear and as an correct if i helped you.

Comment: @ZviVered If you want to download data in parent component and pass it to child's components i will edit answear in a min.

Comment: @ZviVered Or may be i'll first ask what you mean about child ? Because Your question is about routing and all your routes don't have any childs. Can you correct your question?

Comment: Hi. If components are added in real-time and there is not work-around, I will have to run things upon ngOnInit. Best regards.

Comment: @ZviVered Nope they run on their own. You no need to set up any thing there, but if you want to download data to this component you need to write there some code. Or parent component can inject data to child component.

Comment: @ZviVered If it is your first MVC(Model View Component) framework you picked a one harder to learn. Try to read about it first and then program in it. If you have a problem first try to make an good question then google it, you will find an answear faster.

Comment: @ZviVered `ngOnInit()` is one of an "lifecycle-hook" It mean that are triggered on some conditions and you no need to call them. You can read about it here: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks